# How can I update XML element or attribute which its name contains ":" special character

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I have XML file and the elements/attributes names have ":" character, how I can update its vales?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?>
<my:ECR my:NoOfAutho="16" my:hideDetails="0" my:Type="ECR" my:NoOfVBUCMApprovales="10" >
    <my:ECRNo>148</my:ECRNo>
    <my:Stage>Approved</my:Stage>
        <my:Details>
        <my:ReasonForCR>Reason For CR</my:ReasonForCR>
        <my:AreaAffected_Publications_VBUCM>false</my:AreaAffected_Publications_VBUCM>
            <my:AreaAffected_Engineering>true</my:AreaAffected_Engineering>
            <my:AreaAffected_Production>false</my:AreaAffected_Production>
            <my:AreaAffected_CustomerSupport>true</my:AreaAffected_CustomerSupport>
            <my:AreaAffected_VBUCMTest>false</my:AreaAffected_VBUCMTest>
        </my:AreaAffectedVB_UCM>
```

Comment: You might want to read about [XML namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace).

Comment: Please show the code you're using now. Also, FYI, those are not names containing ":". They are names with namespace prefixes.

Comment: XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.Load(file.xml);

XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("ECR/Type");

node.Attributes[0].Value = "XYZ";

xmlDoc.Save(file.xml);

Comment: As @Dthorpe: says, your XML is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML sample is invalid as shown. The `my` prefix is not defined in the XML.

If your XML contained `xmlns:my="schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/…"` then the XML would at least have some hope of being valid.

For manipulating XML with namespaces in .NET code, consider using Linq `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`. I have found Linq's `XNamespace` and `XName` types to be much, much easier to use with the `XDocument` family of classes than the old style `XmlDocument`'s rather clunky handling of namespaces.

Change your XML to add the `xmlns:my` attribute to the root element:

```
<my:MNO xmlns:my="schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/…" my:NoOfAutho="16" etc... >
```

In your C# code, add a reference to the Linq stuff to the top of your source file:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Then use code like this (not checked, may contain syntax typos) to load the xml and access the element:

```
XNamespace ns = "schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/…";
XName MNO_Name = ns + "MNO";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path2);
XElement MNO_Element = doc.Root.Descendants(MNO_Name).Single();
```

You can then read or modify the properties, attributes, and children of the MNO element.

To read the value of `<MNO>100</MNO>`, use `MNO_Element.Value`.

To write a new value to the element, assign to the value property: `MNO_Element.Value = "120";`

`.Single()` asserts that there is exactly one node that matches the selection criteria, similar to the `.SelectSingleNode()` function of `XmlDocument`.

As you can see from this code, the name of the "my" namespace prefix in the XML document is immaterial to the code that processes the XML - it's the URI that the "my" prefix represents that is what is important. The prefix is just shorthand so the the XML writer doesn't have to write long and laborious URIs everywhere.

Writing your XML processing code to be agnostic of the XML namespace prefix is very important because the prefix name can (and will) vary from one XML doc to the next, but the namespace URI will be the same.

Comment: I used   XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.Load(path2);
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("ECO/ECONo");
node.Attributes[0].Value = ECForm.No.ToString();
xmlDoc.Save(path2); but still give me error, how I should write the code to updates for example ECONO element?

Comment: forget my file, here is another XML file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my:Main MName="HELLO" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-12-05T19:18:21">
  <my:MNO>100</my:MNO>
</my:Main>

how I can change values of MNO element and MName attribute using C#?

Comment: I've updated my answer with your new element and namespace strings.

Comment: to start, how can I read the namespace from the xml file, as it is changed each time with new files.

Comment: XElement.Name.NamespaceName will give you the namespace URI.  XElement.Name.Namespace will give you the namespace prefix text.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you mean by "how can I update its values", but it will likely help if you understand that these are [XML namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace).

I.E., `my:ECRNo` has a simple element name of `ECRNo` with a namespace prefix of `my`, which maps to a URN or a URL - which should be declared with a `xmlns:my=...` within the XML (either where it is declared, at a parent, or in the XML root element) - but isn't shown in the XML sample you provided here.

To update this using `XmlNode`, you need to use the overloaded `SelectSingleNode` method that accepts a `XmlNamespaceManager` as the 2nd argument.  You then need to all the `.AddNamespace` method on the namespace manager to register the `my` prefix.  This is detailed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode%28v=VS.90%29.aspx .

Comment: If I want to update for example; Type attribute; should i use XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("my:ECR/my:Type"); ? but it gave me error ":" is special character.

Comment: forget my file, here is another XML file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my:Main MName="HELLO" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-12-05T19:18:21">
  <my:MNO>100</my:MNO>
</my:Main>

how I can change values of MNO element and MName attribute using C#?

Comment: @Waleed - same answer.  I'll provide you with a working code sample later, unless someone else beats me to it (please feel free!).

Answer (score 0):

Colons are not valid characters in xml elements / attributes. They are namespaces.

Your line

```
<my:ECR my:NoOfAutho="16" my:hideDetails="0" my:Type="ECR" my:NoOfVBUCMApprovales="10" >
```

Properly references the `my` namespace already, so you should just be able to do this:

```
<my:ECR NoOfAutho="16" hideDetails="0" Type="ECR" NoOfVBUCMApprovales="10" >
```

And you should be fine?

You will also have to remove the `my:` from other places in the file particularly closing tags

```
</ReasonForCR>
```

Comment: but I need to keep my: in the file and just update the attributes and elements values using XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("my:ECR/my:Type");. how can I make this?

Comment: forget my file, here is another XML file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my:Main MName="HELLO" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-12-05T19:18:21">
  <my:MNO>100</my:MNO>
</my:Main>

how I can change values of MNO element and MName attribute using C#?

Comment: @Waleed I'd recommend updating your question (or making a new one?) to ask this question directly.

Comment: Or you may want to look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229860/editing-an-xml-file